# facebook marketing api - results and cost per result

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-marketing-api

I want to retrieve via API the values for cost per result and results columns of the facebook business manager. Is this possible?

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you ended up finding the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible through the Insight API.

Request insights for a campaign and the cost_per_action_type field. The cost_per_action_type field will be an array containing the cost per result of various action types.

In a traffic campaign the action type of interest is link_click. The value for link_clicks is what you would see under results in the fb ad manager.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/